# Javascript callback not executing in razor MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, dom

I have a razor view page that I want to load some data if I have a value in session storage for the system. I have the following `cshtml`

```
<main class="admin-main" onreadystatechange="testMe">
<!--Hidden content here-->
</main>
```

`testMe` is a callback that I am defining in an external javascript file as the following:

```
function testMe() {
    if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
        console.log("Admin page accessed");
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('special')) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = "/Home/SpecialLogin";
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this in chrome, nothing happens because the javascript never executes. I've tried using both `testMe` and `testMe()` with no avail.

I even tried including it in a script tag and the bottom of the page but still no response. Breakpoint never triggers.

Is there some sort of MVC method to do this that I'm overstepping? Running it with standalone html/css/js works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/readystatechange), the `readystatechange` event is fired when the `readyState` attribute of a document has changed. The `main` tag doesn't have a `readyState` attribute.

You can use jQuery like this, if you want that code to run when the `readyState` of the document is changed:

```
$(document).on('readystatechange', function() {
    if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
        console.log("Admin page accessed");
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('special')) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = "/Home/SpecialLogin";
        }
    }
});
```